# java числа из интервала 1-26 заменить на маленькие буквы латинского алфавита

Tags: java, строки, преобразование

Числа, которые нужно преобразовать в буквы, отделены от остальных символов пробелом, пробелы, которые находятся между заменяемыми числами нужно удалить, символы которые отличаются от чисел не изменять.

Пример:

- `1 8 11 , 26 ! b20` -> `ahk,z! b20`
- `a 14 2 10` -> `anbj`

Как реализовать?

Comment: ahk,z! b20 - тут точно пробел должен быть? Т.е. пробелы убирать только перед и после чисел?

Comment: @insolor должен быть, числа которые нужно преобразовать отделены пробелами и их потом надо удалить, все остальные не трогать !  - не является число из диапазона и b20 не разделены пробелом, так что менять их не  надо.

Comment: В правилах этого сайта (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) написано "Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно".  Почитайте сами, там еще другие полезные советы есть.

Comment: @insolor у вас что-то получилось?

Comment: чему там получаться то, 1) делаете split по пробелу 2) каждую подстроку пытаетесь в число конвертировать 3) если получилось, смотрите в диапазон ли число 4) если в диапазоне, то подменяете на букву 4) в любом противном случае подстроку не трогаете 5) результат join в строку обратно

Comment: @Shadow_fiend у меня вариант через split, примерно как в комменте выше, только собираю все через StringBuilder. Но в этом случае просто съедаются все пробелы. Как сделать чтобы иногда съедались, иногда нет - мне немного лень разбираться. Может позже напишу, если придет какая-нибудь светлая мысль, и вопрос к этому времени не закроют)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, такой код получился:

```
private static String convert(String text) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean prevNotNumber = false;  // Переменная-флаг, где будем хранить, был ли предыдущий элемент числом
    for(String part: text.split(" ")) {
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(part);
            // Из номера буквы получаем саму букву - для этого получаем код буквы 'a',
            // прибавляем номер буквы минус 1 (для буквы a номер будет 1, а чтобы из кода буквы a получить код a, нужно прибавлять 0),
            // потом код буквы приводим опять к символьному типу
            char c = (char)((int)'a' + number - 1);
            result.append(c);
            prevNotNumber = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // Текущий элемент не число, и предыдущий элемент не число - добавляем между ними пробел
            if (prevNotNumber) {  
                result.append(" ");
            }
            result.append(part);
            prevNotNumber = true;
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convert("1 8 11 , 26 ! b20"));
    System.out.println(convert("a 14 2 10"));
}
```

Результат:

```
ahk,z! b20
anbj
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.